# API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. It will be removed at the end of 2019

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting this Warning after i updated dependencies .I've updated gradle plugin, google play services plugin and all the dependencies, but issue is still there.

Comment: Revert only gradle plugin update.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel If i revert then some other dependencies getting issue...like they get deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806004/api-variant-getmergeresources-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with-varian)