# WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with

Tags: java, android

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2019.
>
> For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>
> To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information. Affected Modules: app

Comment: This is just a warning, its safe to ignore that warning for now.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: provide your build.gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806004/api-variant-getmergeresources-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with-varian)

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by Saran in the comments, there is no permanent solution for that as of now. It's a warning that you should be able to safely ignore for now.

You can try,

> Changing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` for now

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem.Is this an google  bug?

Comment: It's not a bug but warning which will get resolved probably in next google-service version 4.3.1 or 4.4.0.